# Resolve content in subdirectory but keep the path in the browser

Tags: apache, .htaccess, redirect, mod-rewrite

My goal is this:

We have site that lives in a webroot which is `/web`.

It contains the `.htaccess` file but we want to serve up the content from `/web/content` but we do not want the URL the user sees to contain `/content` just the initial path they requested.

Example:

The user makes a request to a URL:

```
example.com/color/cool/blue
```

This request goes to:

```
/webroot/color/cool/blue (which does not exist)
```

The content is in

```
/webroot/content/color/cool/blue/index.htm
```

We would like the user to see `example.com/color/cool/blue` in the browser, but see the content from what is `example.com/content/color/cool/blue/index.htm`.

We also would like some directories to be directly accessed like:

```
example.com/exeption/foo.pdf
```

We are doing this as a conversion of a dynamic site to a static site so simply moving everything to the root or switching the webroot are not options.

Comment: "We also would like some directories to be directly accessed like: example/exeption/foo.pdf" - Directories or files? To clarify, `/web` (or `/webroot`) is the document root that `example.com/` maps to?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assumptions:

- Directory file-paths do not contain dots.

In the root `.htaccess` file try the following:

```
# Disable directory listings (mod_autoindex) since "DirectorySlash Off"
Options -Indexes -MultiViews

# Prevent trailing slash being appended to directories
DirectorySlash Off

# File to serve from requested directory
DirectoryIndex index.htm

RewriteEngine On

# Remove trailing slash on any URL that is requested directly (excludes rewritten URLs)
RewriteCond %{ENV:REDIRECT_STATUS} ^$
RewriteRule (.*)/$ /$1 [R=301,L]

# Rewrite root
RewriteRule ^$ content/ [L]

# If request maps to a directory in "/content" then rewrite and append trailing slash
RewriteCond %{DOCUMENT_ROOT}/content/$1 -d
RewriteRule ^([^.]+)$ content/$1/ [L]
```

> We also would like some directories to be directly accessed like: `example/exeption/foo.pdf`

You don't necessarily need to add anything in this respect. Although I'm assuming you mean "files", not "directories".

Comment: This is interesting and thank you but it feels like this looks for requests to /content and remaps them. I'm more looking for them to make the request to the root without the /content but deliver the content from the /content directory without displaying that in the url. Exceptions would be /exception/blue or /exception or /exception/blue/foo

Comment: @kgrondell "I'm more looking for them to make the request to the root without the /content but deliver the content from the /content directory without displaying that in the URL." - Yes, that is exactly what this code does. It does not "look for requests to /content", it checks to see if the request exists as a directory in `/content` before rewriting. You wouldn't necessarily need to actually implement an exception unless `/exception/blue` (for example) also happened to exist as a directory in `/content` (ie. `/content/exception/blue` was also a directory).

Comment: Thanks I gave this a shot. For mapping to /content it works fantastically. I run into issues with any exception folder (they come up 403) and the root of content does not match but this is a great! Start thank you!

Comment: @kgrondell "I run into issues with any exception folder (they come up 403)" - What do you mean by this? If you request a directory that does not contain a `DirectoryIndex` document then mod_autoindex triggers a 403 (providing directory listings are disabled). I realise now what you mean by "the root of content does not match" (after your more [recent question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/72018919/map-requests-for-to-to-display-the-content-from-a-sub-folder)). I've updated my answer.